# Excel power view sheet comes out blank when printing

Tags: excel, printing, powerpivot, powerview

When I try to print a power view sheet it comes out blank (no ink on the paper), even though the print preview shows the sheet nicely.

See image below (secret stuff is blurred out):
[image]

According to Microsoft themselves it should be possible to both print and export (to pdf) a power view sheet.

Many other sites also claim that it should be possible, e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_power_view/excel_power_view_sharing.htm

I have tried both options though, and it comes out blank on paper when printing, and when exported just shows a blank pdf page.

Comment: Has your printer run out of ink....

Comment: As the export also shows a blank pdf, I don't think that is the problem @TimWilkinson

Comment: @TimWilkinson It has plenty of ink. Luuklag Good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting Microsoft support and I was told that it is only possible to print an image of the current view if the Excel document is on a SharePoint server.